# Azure Pipelines deploy user

Tags: azure, virtual-machines

What are the permissions a user has when on a deployment job? Who is this user (whoami)?
It would be really helpful if this user was the default user on my VM (Debian 9) since it doesn't need a password to use sudo and I need to start and stop a service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User is the same as the default user, so it can run `sudo` without password